# PyQt4: emit signal when mouse is released anywhere on the screen

Tags: python, pyqt, signals, mouseevent, pyqt4

the problem is: I have the QListWidget, which selection mode allows to select multiple items by clicking one, dragging, and releasing over the other. I would like to emit signal when mouse is released ANYWHERE on the screen (only if it was first pushed down over some item in the list). How should I do that?

From what I investigated so far:
QListWidget has signal itemSelectionChanged, but this emits signal after each new item is selected while dragging over the items

QListWidget has signal clicked inherited from QAbstractItemView, but this works only if mouse was pushed and released on the same item

I have tried to extend QListWidget class and define in it mouseReleaseEvent, but that overrides original event and ruins proper behavior of the list

I have tried to make blank label with installEventFilter, and create class mouseReleasedFilter, and that worked somehow, but is there more elegant way?

```
class mouseReleasedFilter(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(mouseReleasedFilter, self).__init__(parent)
    def eventFilter(self, object, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonRelease:
        print 'released'
        return False
    return True

self.filter = mouseReleasedFilter(self)

self.label.installEventFilter(self.filter)
```

I would be grateful for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have tried to extend QListWidget class and define in it mouseReleaseEvent, but that overrides original event and ruins proper behavior of the list

That's the correct way to do it; just run the method that you're overriding using `super`:

```
class MyList(QtGui.QListWidget):
    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, e):
        super(MyList, self).mouseReleaseEvent(e)
        print('released', e)
```

Example:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
app = QtGui.QApplication([])
class MyList(QtGui.QListWidget):
    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, e):
        super(MyList, self).mouseReleaseEvent(e)
        print('released', e)

l = MyList()
l.addItems(['hello', 'world'])
l.show()
```

Output:

```
('released', <PyQt4.QtGui.QMouseEvent object at 0x72b4d40>)
('released', <PyQt4.QtGui.QMouseEvent object at 0x72b4d40>)
('released', <PyQt4.QtGui.QMouseEvent object at 0x72b4d40>)
('released', <PyQt4.QtGui.QMouseEvent object at 0x72b4d40>)
('released', <PyQt4.QtGui.QMouseEvent object at 0x72b4d40>)
```